# Parallel execution of an instructions block

Tags: parallelization

I regularly use Parallelize and ParallelMap, andI've been reading the manual pages for parallel computing instructions but i could not find what I am looking for.
Assume I have a sequence of instructions that **I know**  to be uncorrelated:

```
c=a+b;
f=d+e;
i=g+h;
```

Is it possible to execute the three instrunctions in parallel on three different Kernels ?

Comment: You may be able to use [`ParallelEvaluate[yourexpression, kernel]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelEvaluate.html), where kernel is a `KernelObject` returned by the `Kernels[]` command. You will probably have to `DistributeDefinitions` to the parallel kernels first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ParallelMap` with unevaluated list of expressions

```
parallelize[expr_List] := ParallelMap[# &, Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated@expr]
SetAttributes[parallelize, HoldAll];
{a, b} = {FactorInteger[2^500 - 1], FactorInteger[2^331 - 1]} // parallelize;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
LaunchKernels[3]
(* Out: 
        {"KernelObject"[1, "local"], 
         "KernelObject"[2, "local"], 
         "KernelObject"[3, "local"]} 
*)

MapThread[
  ParallelEvaluate[FactorInteger[#1], #2] &,
  {RandomInteger[{10^6, 10^7}, 3], Kernels[]}
]

(*Out:
{
  {{2, 1}, {3, 1}, {334157, 1}},
  {{2, 3}, {59, 1}, {20759, 1}}, 
  {{5, 1}, {11, 1}, {41, 1}, {1667, 1}}
} 
*)
```

Comment: My fault, but I don't fully get the code (that actually don't run on my Mathematica). I must point it out that I want to execute 3 different instructions... maybe having used 3 sums in the example was misleading